# Chrome webstore asking for Host permission justification despite not having it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

After realizing about the delay that comes with having a hosting permission verified, I decided to it take out. My new manifest.json is:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Daily",
    "description": "Manage your calendars smarter!",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "icons":{
        "16": "logo-16.png",
        "48": "logo-48.png",
        "128": "logo-128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "scripts/audio_file.wav", "reminder.html"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "identity.email",
        "tabs",
        "https://www.example.com/yzs",
        "https://www.example.com/xyz"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "background.js", "flipclock-min.js", "script.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

Yet in the developer console I am required to justify why I am using hosting permission. I tried even starting a new process hoping it wouldn't ask anymore but nothing changed. Why is this?

Comment: `https://www.example.com/yzs` is a host permission so the web store wants you to explain why you need it.

Comment: so regardless if you're just using a specified url(s) for API or `<all_urls>`, they are both considered a hosting permission & hence take months for it to be verified?

Comment: Adding a URL in `permissions` gives the extension access to tabs with that site and allows making `fetch` or XMLHttpRequest in extension scripts.